# How to authenticate user using Django-rest and React js

Tags: reactjs, django-rest-framework, django-rest-auth

I am trying to authenticate user with django rest and simple react js without redux

User is successfully authenticated at django rest endpoint (email,password) but when I try to authenticate from react it doesn't show any results and I am unable to find it.From react end I take user input via form and save in state and send the states to endpoint using POST method.But at django end nothing happens.Here's below my logic:

```
class login extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state={
        email:"",
        password:"",
    }
}

submitForm=(evt)=>{
    evt.preventDefault();
    const form= {
        email: this.state.email,
        password: this.state.password
    };

    this.loginUser(form)
};

loginUser=(payload)=>{
    console.log("In fetch request");
    console.log(payload);
    fetch(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/chauffeur/login_user/`,
        {
            method:'POST',
            body: JSON.stringify(payload),
            headers:{
                'Content-Type':'application/json'
            }
        }).then(response =>{
            if (response.status===200){
                return response.json().then(data=>{
                    return {status:"ok",data}
                })
            }
            else
            {
                console.log("Unable to access")
            }
    }).catch(error => console.error('Error:', error))

    setInputValue = (e, inputName) => {
    this.setState({[inputName]: e.target.value})
};

render(){
    return(
        <div>
            <form onSubmit={this.submitForm}>
                <input type='email' placeholder="email" value={this.state.email} onChange={(e) => this.setInputValue(e, 'email')}/>
                <input type='password' placeholder="password" value={this.state.password} onChange={(e) => this.setInputValue(e, 'password')}/>
                <button type="submit">SignIn</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    )
}
```

I tried to see json response after request but nothing comes on console.Kindly give some suggestions how to fix this.

Comment: code seems ok, but you need to tell us how your authentication work from backend side (cookie, token?).

Comment: I have used Simple token authentication, when the user is created a token is assigned to it.

Comment: Then you should save your token to global state. Check in network tab from devtools if you are getting proper response. Btw. consider using prettier/eslint for clean code formatting.